# Implicitly differentiating a function

Tags: calculus

We have $$9x + 27y - \dfrac{10}{81}(x+y)^3 = 0 $$ I want to find the tangent to this curve in the origin so I was given the tip (on this site) to implicitly differentiate.

My question is how would you do this here? We have:

$$ 9x + 27y - \dfrac{10x^3}{81} - \dfrac{10x^2y}{27} - \dfrac{10xy^2}{27} - \dfrac{10y^3}{81} = 0$$

But in the wikipedia article I was linked, it doesn't really explain how to deal with terms with 2 variables. So how would I obtain the derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to expand the powers. You treat $y$ as function in $x$ and differentiate for $x$
$$
0=9+27y'+\frac{10}{81}·3(x+y)^2(1+y')
$$
and insert $x=0$, $y(0)=0$ to get
$$
0=9+27y'(0)+\frac{10}{81}·3(0+0)^2(1+y'(0))=9+27y'(0)
$$
to get $y'(0)=-\frac13$.

Comment: So the tangent in the origin is $y=-\dfrac{1}{3}x$. I see. Kind of weird, in the question they say that sufficiently close to the origin, the curve is the graph of an infinitely differentiable function $f$ (which is defined on a small, open interval which includes 0). However, this indicates that the third derivative already is $0$. Or do they mean that only in the points close to the origin the function is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering, would this mean that $f"(0) = 0$, or do you have to implicitly differentiate twice?

Comment: The implicit function theorem tells you additionally that if $F(x,y)$ is $C^k$ and $F_y$ invertible at some solution $F(x_0,y_0)=0$ then the implicit function $y(x)$ solving $F(x,y(x))=0$ close to $(x_0,y_0)$ is also $C^k$. Since polynomials are $C^{\infty}$, so is the implicit function of this task. And yes, the second derivative is obtained by again implicitly differentiating. Or you could insert $y(x)=-\frac13x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+O(x^4)$ into the equation and compare coefficients of the lowest powers of $x$.

Comment: @LutzL Implicitly differentiating twice would simply give $0=27y"(0) \rightarrow y"(0)=0$ right? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Yes. It is only the third derivative that reduces the third power to a constant (times non-zero factors).